# Samba Server Configured in Fedora 13 ,but unable to access from windows

Tags: linux, networking, file-sharing, samba, fedora-13

Configuration file :/etc/samba/smb.conf as follows

```
[global]
        workgroup = workgroup
        server string = SambaServer
        security = user
        name resolve order = hosts lmhosts
;       encrypt passwords = yes
        guest ok = yes
        guest account = arun

[admin]
        path = /tmp/admin
        read only = no
;       browseable = yes
        guest ok = yes
```

I am able to ping the target Machine from Windows, but while trying

```
\\192.168.1.201\admin from windows PC, it shows Error: The Network path not found
```

One more thing I observer is while trying below command from another Linux Machine it shows below error,But while trying from the same Linux host(which the samba is configured) it working.

```
smbclient -U user1 -L \\192.168.1.201
connection to 192.168.1.201 failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)
```

Comment: Why are there two different IPs here? I see both 192.168.1.201 and 192.168.10.101.

Comment: Did you create a samba password for `user1` with `smbpasswd -a user1`? Samba can't use the system passwords because they're hashed and the only thing you can do with hashed passwords is verify them against the plaintext password.

Comment: Hi @terdon I thought to avoid actual IP address , but missed to modify in all lines.

Comment: Hi @David Schwartz Yes I created a samba passwd that time , Actually it was problem with Firewall, Now I solved the issue .. Thanks for your interest guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled Samba in Samba Server's Firewall solved the Issue [Menu: Sytem>Administration > Firewall]

Answer (score 1):

the string format is wrong

*smbclient -U user1 -L \192.168.1.201*

change it to:

*smbclient -U user1 -L 192.168.1.201*
or
*smbclient -U user1 -L \YOURHOSTNAME*

where hostname is the name you have given in your /etc/samba/smb.conf file

*[global]*
*workgroup = YOURWORKGROUP*(change it to what ever is the name in your local net)
*netbios name = YOURHOSTNAME* (must be different from workgoup name)

Also you have to set your desired host name
using the command
*hostname YOURHOSTNAME*

after that
*sudo systemctl restart smb.service*
*sudo systemctl restart nmb.service*

Comment: Hi @dbach , I both are working in my case **smbclient -U user1 -L \\192.168.1.201** and **smbclient -U user1 -L 192.168.1.201**

Answer (score 0):

Check samba is started:

"chkconfig --levels 235 smb on"
"/etc/init.d/smb start"

This will auto start it at boot.

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting can't get back ticks on my phone!

Comment: Hi @Shutupsquare,  
Yes samba is running , I just restarted once again using command  
**"service smb restart"**
(Okay sure I will do that suggested modification to start it while booting)